# Display Bitmap that is stored in window dc

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I have used bitmap stored in Memory DC to copy it into window DC and display it on screen properly using `BitBlt`.

But now that bitmap image is already copied during 1st time. For the 2nd time how do i display the image that is stored in window DC bitmap but not copy it again from memory dc to window dc.

Comment: C != C++. Tag with only one of them.

Comment: `LoadImage` is usually the slowest function here, specially if it is loading image from file. You may want to save the `HBITMAP` it returns. `BitBlt` is also relatively slow, but you can't do anything about that. `BitBlt` is necessary. You can save other variables in heap but it won't improve performance. Show your code...

Comment: No, you need one of the BitBlt family of functions (other than writing the image pixel by pixel, which is too slow).

Comment: You raised a flag to ask whether it would be appropriate to tag with both C and C++ because the Windows API functions are the same in both languages. While it's true that the Windows API is a C API, and therefore you'd generally use the functions in the same way from a C++ application, the language tag you use should be determined by which language you're writing/compiling the code in. If you're writing C code, then use [c]. If you're writing C++ code, then use [c++]. A single language tag is best, because C and C++ are different languages, and the answers may be different.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Do you have any evidence for `BitBlt` being *"relatively slow"*?

Comment: @IInspectable `BitBlt` is slow relative to other GDI functions such as `CreateCompatibleDC`. A full screen `BitBlt` is about 5 milliseconds on a low end computer. Albeit, it's still faster than monitor frequency and what human eye can pick up. The OP has changed the question, my comment is not relevant now.

Answer (score 2):

`BitBlt` is *not* a slow function. It has been heavily accelerated by graphics cards since the early 1990s, and it's called all over the place in the operating system. There will be no performance problems observed from blitting.

Therefore, the correct thing to do is to call `BitBlt` in response to your window's `WM_PAINT` message. You will blit from the memory DC (into which the bitmap is loaded) onto your window's DC. This will "draw" the bitmap on the window.

The expensive operations here are creating the memory DC and loading the bitmap. If you want to optimize the display of the bitmap, then do these things once (*e.g.*, when the "viewer" window is created) and cache the memory DC, re-using it each time you need to redraw the window. That way, the only thing you're doing is blitting from one DC to another, which as I said above, is blazingly fast.